# Linking statically against pion network library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-linking, multiple-definition-error, pion-net

I am trying to link pion network library 4.0.3 in my application. I tried to simply compile pion::netlib in RELEASE_STATIC mode - which worked. However, when I linked against it in my application I get alot of unresolved externals.

Then I found out that RELEASE_STATIC configuration defines PION_STATIC_LINKING, and from another post about another library I found out I probably need to define PION_STATIC_LINKING in my program aswell.

Doing so yields a few 100 errors along the following template:

```
error LNK2005: _tolower already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) C:\Users\name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\myproj\LIBCMT.lib(tolower.obj)  myproj
```

I tried to use /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt but I still get errors that say certain functions already defined in pion-common.lib / pion-net.lib.

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could most probably be because you are compiling your project using /MT (Multi-threaded) settings for Code Generation, while pion network library was compiled using /MD (Multi-threaded DLL) or vice-versa. Try changing your configuration to /MD if it's /MT or vice-versa. To do this, go to `Project -> <ProjectName> Properties... -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation`. In the right panel you should be able to see the setting `Runtime Library`. Change the options there and rebuild your whole solution.

Comment: Hey thanks, you were quite right! Can you point me towards some buzzword I can google or some article/resource I can read to help me understand the difference between the code generation setting DLL and the "configuration typ" / output setting DLL?

Comment: In simple terms, your C++ applications, when distributed to other machines need to have CRT (C Run TIme) libs of the same version you compiled against when you use /MD. However, when you use /MT, the dependent libraries gets statically-linked to your application and hence do not require the target machine to have the CRT installed. More about it in a discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/cb662a7a-19a6-44f6-9d87-93b05280801b/